# How to add custom fonts in Apache POI ppt

Tags: java, fonts, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am able to add fonts which are default in Apache POI ppt but not able to add custom fonts. This is what I currently have:

```
XSLFTextBox categoryTitleShape = indexslide.createTextBox();
categoryTitleShape.setAnchor(new java.awt.Rectangle(25, 40, 120, 30));
XSLFTextRun categoryTitle = categoryTitleShape.addNewTextParagraph().addNewTextRun();
categoryTitle.setText("CATEGORIES"); // visible text
categoryTitle.setFontSize(20.);
categoryTitle.setFontColor(Color.BLACK);
categoryTitle.setBold(true);
categoryTitle.setFontFamily(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL, FontGroup.EAST_ASIAN);
```

The above code adds fonts which are available in Apache POI ppt, but I need to add custom fonts. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a font embedding possible in Microsoft Office documents. At least in PowerPoint and Word. See [How to embed fonts in PowerPoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/826832/how-to-embed-fonts-in-powerpoint) and [How to embed a TrueType font in a document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290952/how-to-embed-a-truetype-font-in-a-document). But unfortunately `apache poi`does not supporting storing this font files in `/fonts/` part of the Office  Open XML document files.

So using `apache poi` until now the fonts used must be installed in the operating system. We only can give a string as the `typeface` in [XSLFTextRun.setFontFamily](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFTextRun.html#setFontFamily-java.lang.String-). If this font is installed in the operating system, then it will be used, else a similar font will be guessed if the file is rendered.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class CreatePPTXTextBoxSpecialFont {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

  XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();

  XSLFTextBox textbox = slide.createTextBox(); 
  textbox.setAnchor(new Rectangle(50, 100, 570, 100));
  XSLFTextParagraph paragraph = textbox.addNewTextParagraph(); 
  XSLFTextRun run = paragraph.addNewTextRun();
  run.setText("Arial ");
  run.setFontFamily("Arial");
  run.setFontSize(24d);
  run = paragraph.addNewTextRun();
  run.setText("Algerian ");
  run.setFontFamily("Algerian");
  run.setFontSize(24d);
  run = paragraph.addNewTextRun();
  run.setText("Courier ");
  run.setFontFamily("Courier");
  run.setFontSize(24d);
  run = paragraph.addNewTextRun();
  run.setText("Times New Roman ");
  run.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
  run.setFontSize(24d);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreatePPTXTextBoxSpecialFont.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```

Result in PowerPoint Windows 10:

[image]

Result in Libreoffice Impress Ubuntu Linux:

[image]

Comment: ... but for XSLF [fonts can be embedded](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/201310.mbox/<525B017B.90804@gmx.de>) ... but there are also limits (permission to install the font) to this approach

Comment: @kiwiwings: Thank you for this. I had not known. There is https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2015/07/06/document-font-embedding-demystified/?eu=true which seems to give further insights. But the SSL certificate is outdated. `grmbl` Microsoft! Will nevertheless give it a try and read this.

Comment: @kiwiwings: Well the insights are not as much as the sensational title "Document font embedding demystified " has promised ;-). Do you know whether `apache poi` does plan providing font embedding feature in `XWPF` and/or `XSLF` in future?

Comment: I've did [some work on it](https://github.com/kiwiwings/pptx-shape-exporter), but because of the sfntly dependency I didn't dare to put it in