# Using POI to change font color for a part of text in textbox

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to create textboxes in a .ppt file using POI. The problem is, when I try to change the font color of only **a part of** the text in the textbox, only can I find in the official docs is that there is a method called `RichTextRun.setFontColor()` which could only change the **whole part of** font color of it. Is there any methods in POI which can do that job?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920767/how-to-add-custom-fonts-in-apache-poi-ppt llok this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's really helped!